# What does 15/13 mean with pilot schedule?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-schedules

Saw that this when looking at a part 135 corporate pilot job. What does this mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That generally refers to days on / days off.  In this example you could expect 15 days on duty, followed by 13 days off.